# is there anyway to do this in a loop in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I made this html file a long time ago to display manga images, and now I need this file but I don't know html (I know python)

this how it displays the images with the ability to remove the next images if it don't exist

```
   <p class="text" id="80">80</p><img draggable="false" src="80.png" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove(); $('#79').nextAll('p').remove();" title="80.png">
   <p class="text" id="81">81</p><img draggable="false" src="81.png" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove(); $('#80').nextAll('p').remove();" title="81.png">
   <p class="text" id="82">82</p><img draggable="false" src="82.png" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove(); $('#81').nextAll('p').remove();" title="82.png">
   <p class="text" id="83">83</p><img draggable="false" src="83.png" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove(); $('#82').nextAll('p').remove();" title="83.png">
   <p class="text" id="84">84</p><img draggable="false" src="84.png" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove(); $('#83').nextAll('p').remove();" title="84.png">
   <p class="text" id="85">85</p><img draggable="false" src="85.png" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove(); $('#84').nextAll('p').remove();" title="85.png">
   <p class="text" id="86">86</p><img draggable="false" src="86.png" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove(); $('#85').nextAll('p').remove();" title="86.png">
   <p class="text" id="87">87</p><img draggable="false" src="87.png" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove(); $('#86').nextAll('p').remove();" title="87.png">
   <p class="text" id="88">88</p><img draggable="false" src="88.png" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove(); $('#87').nextAll('p').remove();" title="88.png">
```

is there anyway to make this better like a loop to display existing images?
and even with this method it shows the element for number 84, why?
[num 84](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv4sB.png)

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 options:

1. Do the logic in JavaScript
2. Do the logic in the backend (aka server-side)

You can't achieve this using HTML only since HTML is not a programming language.